# Euler Challenge 1 in Java - I'm doing something wrong?

Tags: java, arrays, sum

http://projecteuler.net/problem=1

Hey. I'm a high schooler trying to get a good grasp on programming problems, so I visited Project Euler. For Problem 1, I wrote up some code in Java that would of solved it, but something is evidently going wrong. Can I get some insight as to what?

Explanation:
I stop everything at the index value of 332 because Java counts from 0, and 333 * 3 is 999 which is below 1,000. Apples is a seperate class with pretty much the same code, although it counts for 5. At the end, I manually add together the two answers, but it wasn't right. What am I doing wrong?
The two final sums are:

Three: 164838

Five: 97515

```
public class Learning {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int three[] = new int[333];
        int counter = 0;
        three[332] = 0;
        int totalthree = 0;
        int threeincrementer = 1;
        int grandtotal;
        boolean run = true;
        boolean runagain = true;


        for (counter = 1; counter<=332; counter++){
            three[counter] = 3 * counter;
            if (!(three[332] == 0)){
                System.out.println("Finished three.");

                while (run == true){
                    totalthree = totalthree + three[threeincrementer];
                    threeincrementer++;
                    if (threeincrementer >= 332){
                        run = false;
                        System.out.println("Three final is: " + totalthree);
                        }       
                    }
                }


        if (runagain == true){
        apples ApplesObject = new apples();
        ApplesObject.rerun(0);
        runagain = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Print out information with `System.out` and less iterations to see where calculations go wrong. That's basic debugging, and what you should do before you ask on StackOverflow.

Comment: Don't use `System.out` use a bloody debugger.

Comment: In your problem statement you say 'Java counts from 0' but why is that the case?  Your counter is counting from 1 to 332, why would java do any different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some numbers are at the same time multiplication of 3 AND 5 like 15 so you shouldn't separately calculate sum of all multiplications of 3 and multiplications of 5 and than add them because you will end up doing something like

```
sum3 = 3,6,9,12,15,...

sum5 = 5,10,15,...
```

so first `sum3` will include 15, and `sum5` will also include it which means you will add 15 two times. Now to balance your calculations you will need to subtract from your `sum3+sum5` sum which will add all multiplications of 15

```
sum15 = 15,30,45,...
```

So using your approach your final formula should look like `sum3+sum5-sum15`.

But simpler solution for this problem can look like

```
sum = 0 
for each X in 1...999 
   if (X is multiplication of 3) OR (X is multiplication of 5)
      add X to sum
```

To check if some number X is multiplication of number Y you can use [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator `%` (example `reminder = X % Y`) which finds the remainder of division of one number by another.

You can find more Java operators [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Comment: Didn't think of that. I don't think programming is cut out for me: thank you!

Comment: @user113580 You are welcome :). BTW, I'ma not gonna lie, programming is not easiest thing, but it definitely IS for everyone (it just requires lot of persistence and practice, also different people learn different things with different speed so don't give up so easily).

Comment: @user113580 Don't give up so easily! Accidentally counting the 15s twice is a really easy thing to miss when counting the multiples of 3 and 5. The important thing is to learn from it. Cheers!